# Set check box value programmatically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a check box in HTML:

```
<td class="myClass">
    Delete<br><input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheck" class="delete" name="delete" value="">
</td>
```

I am trying to set its value programmatically using jQuery, but it is not setting the value:

```
prot.find("#delete").attr("value", "12345");//here prot is reference to table row
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem is, you're trying to find an element with ID `delete`. The checkbox however has the ID `deleteCheck` doesn't have that ID, it only has that name. Your code will work if you change it to

```
prot.find("#deleteCheck").attr("value", "12345");
```

but more elegantly, use the `.val()` method:

```
prot.find("#deleteCheck").val("12345");
```

**EDIT**:
General note, more than one element on the page with the same ID is a bad idea and against the HTML spec. If you only have one checkbox with that ID, there's no need to use the `prot.find`-part, instead just use `$('#deleteCheck')`.

Answer (score 4):

Try like

```
$("#deleteCheck").val('12345');
```

OR

```
$(".delete").val('12345');
```

`deleteCheck` is your **id** that should be selected with `#` and `delete` is your **class** that should be selected with `.`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
prot.find("#delete").val("12345");
```

Instead of:

```
prot.find("#delete").attr("value", "12345");
```

Since the `val` can set the value of the field having `delete` as its ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#deleteCheck')[0].value = '12345';
```

or

```
$('#deleteCheck').val('12345');
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **HTML**

```
<td class="myClass">
    Delete<br><input type="checkbox" id="deleteCheck" class="delete" name="delete" value="">
</td>
```

dont do action base on checkbox id="deleteCheck"

In **Jquery**

you can write

```
$("table tr").find(":checkbox").val("set value here")'
```

or can also done by

```
$("table tr .delete").val("set value here")'
```